# go grpc tls mutual auth with self-signed client certs bad certificate

Tags: go, grpc

Does Go gRPC support mutual TLS using self-signed client certs? I'm trying to get mutual TLS working on Go gRPC, and I generated self-signed certs for the server and client using `src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go`, and  the client is failing to connect with the server stating it's a bad cert.

Here's the relevant server code:

```
// load server cert/key, cacert
srvcert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.pem", "key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("SERVER: unable to read server key pair: %v", err)
}
pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../client/client.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("SERVER: unable to read client pem: %v", err)
}
certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
if ok := certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
    log.Fatalf("SERVER: unable to add client cert to pool: %v", err)
}
ta := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{srvcert},
    ClientCAs:    certPool,
    ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
})

lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":51150")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("SERVER: unable to listen: %v", err)
}
s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(ta))
pb.RegisterExpoServer(s, &server{})
if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("SERVER: failed to serve: %v", err)
}
```

And the relevant client code:

```
// load client cert/key, cacert
clcert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("client.pem", "key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("CLIENT: unable to load client pem: %v", err)
}
srvcert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../server/server.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("CLIENT: unable to load server cert: %v", err)
}
caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
if ok := caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(srvcert); !ok {
    log.Fatalf("CLIENT: unable to load server cert pool: %v", err)
}

ta := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{clcert},
    RootCAs:      caCertPool,
})
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:51150", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(ta))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("CLIENT: unable to dial: %v", err)
}

c := pb.NewExpoClient(conn)
```

The client is able to dial okay, but the error comes when trying to call an RPC on the client:

```
2018/07/28 19:32:18 CLIENT: unable to checkin: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
```

Comment: I ran your code but I can't reproduce your problem, it ran fine on my end, so I think it's likely something else (maybe your certificates are invalid)? (I generated two pairs of self-signed certificates with the command `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.pem` to test with.)

Comment: Interesting - when generating the certs with `openssl` as you described, it works fine. I guess the problem is with the certs generated by `generate_cert.go` - although it allows for a hostname (and when just using the server cert from that, it works fine).

Comment: Ah. generate_cert.go does not set`ExtKeyUsageClientAuth`. I'm guessing that's the issue.